# Ubuntu20.04 with kernel4.4 cannot link to Internet through WiFi

Tags: wireless

I want to deploy Ubuntu 20.04 on my board with rockchip 3399. I use kernel4.4 and WiFi/BT driver for rtl8821cu in "drivers/net/wireless/rockchip_wlan/rtl8821cu". But i encountered some probleams as follow:

1. There are 2 wifi interfaces named wlx74ee2aaf63d8 and wlx76ee2aaf63d8 which have same MAC.
2. BT function cannot use though I turned on BTUSB before compiling kernel.
3. When I connected WiFi，it can ping local network well but cannot ping Internet address like google.com.

I found some post said that there are drivers provided by individual can solve the 2nd issue. I tried  https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU  but it didn't work.

Have anyone encountered the similar problem or solved it?

Comment: I found that WiFi cannot ping google.com issue related to DNS purse. I have configured /etc/resolve.conf and wired network connected to my router can ping google.com.

Comment: I use ifconfig wlx76ee2aaf63d8 down to close the 2nd interface. Now the wifi can ping google.com well. But I dont find out why there are two interfaces for only one WiFi chip. And the weird name of wlan interfaces sames explained in this :https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/. The Blu-Tooth function still not work and I doubt that the 2nd wlan interfaces is the mistakenly probed BT module .